# Incorrect boolean return -- CodeIgniter PHP Ion Auth

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to thank you all in advance for taking a look at this! I am quite perplexed as to why this is not working:

My Controller:

```
$ownertest = $this->ion_auth->is_owner();
$grouptest = $this->ion_auth->in_group(2);


var_dump($ownertest); // echos TRUE
var_dump($grouptest); // echos TRUE
```

I am attempting to return "TRUE" for both `$ownertest` and `$grouptest`.
The former function result always comes back TRUE as expected, this is good.

However, the latter function result (`$grouptest`) only returns TRUE when I pass the number 2 directly into it.

***THE PROBLEM***:
I don't know why `$grouptest` result is returning false when I pass`$groupid` into it! When I echo `$groupid` the result is 2. Here is an example:

```
$groupid = $this->ion_auth->get_users_groups()->row()->id;
echo $groupid; // echos "2" in my browser

$ownertest = $this->ion_auth->is_owner();
$grouptest = $this->ion_auth->in_group($groupid)
```

;

```
    var_dump($ownertest); // dumps TRUE
    var_dump($grouptest); // dumps FALSE
```

I would have assumed that `$groupid` being 2 would result in a TRUE return within this function. I cannot figure this out. Does anyone have any suggestions?

I can post Ion Auth's  in_group function code if needed!

Answer (score 3):

Do following 
Cast your variable type to integer

```
$grouptest = $this->ion_auth->in_group((int)$groupid);
```

Comment: Sometimes I wonder how I would get by without this website. Thank you so much, it works perfectly. Sorry to be asking such noob questions, but I could not find a similar thread.